# How to add the extracted values from raster stack to the data.frame of the Spatial object using terra package?

Tags: r, r-raster, terra

I want to add the extracted values from raster stack to the data.frame of the Spatial object using `terra` package

```
f <- system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
#Plot the raster
plot(r, 1:3)

#Create a vector file
points <- cbind.data.frame(Longitude = 40, Latitude = 40, val = 0.5)
points <- rbind.data.frame(points-1, points, points+1)
points_vect <- vect(points, geom=c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs=crs(r, proj=T),
     type = "points")

#Extract the values from raster using the point vector
terra::extract(r, points_vect, xy = T, method = "simple")

#>   ID red green blue  x  y
#> 1  1 255   255  253 30 30
#> 2  2 149   159  186 40 40
#> 3  3 146   156  207 50 50
```

As you can see from the output `val` filed is not there which we used to get using `sp` aurgument of `raster` package. Now how can I have the `val` field added in the extracted data.frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `terra::extract` extract values with the order of elements in the vector, you can simply `cbind` the field to the extracted dataframe or add the needed field as a column with `$`

```
ex <- terra::extract(r, points_vect, xy = T, method = "simple")
ex$val <- points_vect$val
```

**EDIT**

The fastest option for extracting raster values is `exact_extract` in the `exactextract` package, which has an argument (called `append_cols`) to attach the vector field to the data.frame resulting from the extraction.
`exact_extract` accepts only polygon data (as `sf` object) as input, but you can get around this by applying a buffer to your points and summarise the values. See the example below

```
library(exactextractr)
library(sf)

point_sf <- st_as_sf(points_vect)
point_sf <- st_buffer(point_sf,1)
ex <- exactextractr::exact_extract(stack(r),point_sf,fun="mean",append_cols="val")
#you can summarise values using a vector of functions
ex <- exactextractr::exact_extract(stack(r),point_sf,fun=c("mean","median","max","min"),append_cols="val")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that can be done. But I wanted that how it can be implemented using the `extract` function itself as it is available with `raster::extract`.

Comment: I don't think `terra::extract` has such an argument. I guess if you want to use `terra` instead of `raster`, it is because you have speed issues. In that case, I would opt for `exact_extract`  in the `exactextract` package, which is absolutely the fastest solution for raster extraction and has an argument (called `include_cols`) to attach the vector field to the data.frame resulting from the extraction. The only problem is that it only accepts polygon as input, but the simplest solution is to create a small buffer around points and summarise values with a function (such as `mean` or `median`).

Comment: if you are interested in this solution I can edit my answer to include such a case

Comment: You can provide that option also.

Answer (score 6):

As long as you are extracting with points (or use a summarizing function with lines and polygons), you can use `bind=TRUE`

Example data

```
f <- system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
points <- data.frame(Longitude = 40, Latitude = 40, val = 0.5)
points <- rbind(points-1, points, points+1)
points_vect <- vect(points, geom=c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs=crs(r))
points_vect
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : points 
# dimensions  : 3, 3  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 39, 41, 39, 41  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
# names       : Longitude Latitude   val
# type        :     <num>    <num> <num>
# values      :        39       39  -0.5
#                      40       40   0.5
#                      41       41   1.5
```

Solution

```
v <- terra::extract(r, points_vect, xy = T, method = "simple", bind=T)
v
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : points 
# dimensions  : 3, 6  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 39, 41, 39, 41  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : Cartesian (Meter) 
# names       :   val   red green  blue     x     y
# type        : <num> <int> <int> <int> <num> <num>
# values      :  -0.5   247   254   255  39.5  38.5
#                 0.5   149   159   186  40.5  39.5
#                 1.5   132   141   182  41.5  40.5
```

---

Alternative approaches:

First extract

```
v <- terra::extract(r, points_vect, xy = T, method = "simple")
v
#  ID red green blue  x  y
#1  1 247   254  255 39 39
#2  2 149   159  186 40 40
#3  3 132   141  182 41 41
```

Then use `cbind` to combine the extracted values `v` with `points_vect`

```
x <- cbind(points_vect, v)
x     
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : points 
# dimensions  : 3, 9  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 39, 41, 39, 41  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
# names       : Longitude Latitude   val    ID   red green  blue     x     y
# type        :     <num>    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# values      :        39       39  -0.5     1   247   254   255    39    39
#                      40       40   0.5     2   149   159   186    40    40
#                      41       41   1.5     3   132   141   182    41    41
```

Or replace the original values like this

```
values(points_vect) <- v
points_vect
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : points 
# dimensions  : 3, 6  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 39, 41, 39, 41  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
# names       :    ID   red green  blue     x     y
# type        : <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# values      :     1   247   254   255    39    39
#                   2   149   159   186    40    40
#                   3   132   141   182    41    41
```

You can also create a new `SpatVector` like this

```
newpts <- vect(v, c("x", "y"), crs=crs(r))
newpts
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : points 
# dimensions  : 3, 6  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 39, 41, 39, 41  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
# names       :    ID   red green  blue     x     y
# type        : <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# values      :     1   247   254   255    39    39
#                   2   149   159   186    40    40
#                   3   132   141   182    41    41
```